# curl returning null value

Tags: php, json, curl

I am working on Geo coding some addresses and I found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525561/using-php-curl-to-pull-data-from-json-google-maps-api) that uses cURL to extract the json data. For some reason it keeps returning `null` I have echoed the `$url` and copied it into the address field of my browser and it works as intended so I know the URL is valid. Does anyone spot a mistake in my code?

```
for($count=0; $count < count($uploadedArray); $count++) {
    $address = "";
    $address .= $uploadedArray[$count]["Address"] . " ";
    $address .= $uploadedArray[$count]["City"] . ", ";
    $address .= $uploadedArray[$count]["State"] . " ";
    $address .= $uploadedArray[$count]["Zip"];
    $url = urlencode("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $address . "=%s&sensor=false");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $geoloc = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
    var_dump($geoloc);
    echo $geoloc['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']; // get lat for json
    echo $geoloc['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']; // get ing for json
}
```

Comment: PS you don't need to use CURL just use `file_get_contents($url)`, and encode it as stated below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) on the whole url. You should use it only on the parameters:

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . urlencode($address) . "=%s&sensor=false";
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't urlencode the url. Just the parameters.

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . urlencode($address) . "=%s&sensor=false";
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using file_get_contents?
If you need to send some extra parameters, use the context option.