# Get the lat,lng base on address

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

## I have

an array of user addresses

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => " Admin"
    "address" => "111 Park AveFloor 4 New York, NY"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "User A"
    "address" => "12 Main Street Cambridge, MA"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Apple  HQ"
    "address" => "1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, California"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Google MA"
    "address" => "355 Main St Cambridge, MA"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "site HQ"
    "address" => "300 Concord Road  Billerica, MA "
  ]
]
```

---

## My goal

is to grab the `lat`, and `lng` of each address, and construct something like this

```
[
    ["Admin", 18.3114513, -66.9219513, 0],
    ["User A", 25.3253982, 44.5503772, 1],
    ["Apple  HQ", 33.0241101, 39.5865834, 2],
    ["Google MA", 43.9315743, 20.2366877, 3],
    ["site HQ", 32.683063, 35.27481, 4]
]
```

so I can plot them in Google Map.

---

## I tried:

making a curl to

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&key=***
```

`$data = shell_exec('curl '.$url);`

---

## I got

this back as a response, after decode it

`$data = json_decode($data);`

```
{#278 ▼
  +"results": array:1 [▼
    0 => {#298 ▼
      +"address_components": array:2 [▶]
      +"formatted_address": "PR-111, Puerto Rico"
      +"geometry": {#300 ▼
        +"bounds": {#301 ▶}
        +"location": {#304 ▼
          +"lat": 18.3114513
          +"lng": -66.9219513
        }
        +"location_type": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER"
        +"viewport": {#305 ▶}
      }
      +"place_id": "ChIJrdMXucS4AowRF4jHu2ji58U"
      +"types": array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
  +"status": "OK"
}
```

---

As you can see, now I can access the lat,lng by accessing

`$location = $data->results[0]->geometry->location;`

You might say, if you can access to it - why are you still asking this question ?

Well, that **lat,lng** data that I'm getting back from the API response produce wrong Google Map Marker.

I'm not sure why/how it is wrong, but I am **sure** that all my user addresses are in the US, and here is my Google Map Marker Result. None of them showing inside the US.

## Google Map Result

[image]

---

I'm running out of ideas now.

Any hints / helps / suggestions will mean a lot to me.

---

## Update

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35140495/4480164)

I be able to get the **lat,lng** and plot correct markers on my Google Map now.

---

## Final Result

[image]

Comment: you are searching for somewhat generic address. what would happen if you tagged "USA" onto the end of them?

Comment: Hmm good call, let me try.

Comment: Regardless of the actual problem, *this* is a really well structured question (+1).

Comment: Nice you put a box around the US for those who don't know where it is :)

Comment: You could also try adding zip code, and make sure that the $address is URL encoded. It looks like in your example, the geocoder API returned the formatted address as Puerto Rico, so it may not be reading it correctly. Here's the FAQ on formatting the address: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_queryformat

Comment: @trincot: As from Belgium/Germany: do we really care ;-) ?

Comment: I have to ask why are you using `shell_exec` ... `$data = shell_exec('curl '.$url);` ... just use `json_decode(file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($address) . '&key=*******'))` ... my guess is that the spaces in the address are messing up your curl request via the shell.

Comment: @cmorrissey: I've tried your suggestion, I got `file_get_contents(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=111 Park AveFloor 4 New York,NY,10022,USA&amp;key=****): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request`

Comment: don't url encode the & between address and key

Comment: I just tested your shell_exe implementation and its totally the spaces in the address that messing it up.

Comment: Here is how I construct my `$full_address = $add1.$add2. $city.','.$state.','.$postal_code.','.$country;` Should I do it differently ? Please advise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PHP (curl) to pull data from JSON (Google Maps API)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525561/using-php-curl-to-pull-data-from-json-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should url-encode your address before you pass it to curl.

```
urlencode($address);
```

The spaces in the addresses if not encoded can cause unpredictable problems.

Here is an example of what happens:

**Without url encoding:**

```
curl https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=111 Park AveFloor 4 New York, NY

{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "111",
               "short_name" : "PR-111",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Puerto Rico",
               "short_name" : "PR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "PR-111, Puerto Rico",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.4485405,
                  "lng" : -66.6643718
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.2420721,
                  "lng" : -67.15701799999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.3114513,
               "lng" : -66.9219513
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.4485405,
                  "lng" : -66.6643718
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.2420721,
                  "lng" : -67.15701799999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJrdMXucS4AowRF4jHu2ji58U",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**With url encoding:**

```
curl https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=111+Park+AveFloor+4+New+York%2C+NY
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "111",
               "short_name" : "111",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Park Avenue",
               "short_name" : "Park Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Midtown East",
               "short_name" : "Midtown East",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Manhattan",
               "short_name" : "Manhattan",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "New York",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York County",
               "short_name" : "New York County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "10170",
               "short_name" : "10170",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "111 Park Ave, New York, NY 10170, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7522096,
                  "lng" : -73.9773591
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7521971,
                  "lng" : -73.97736809999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.7521971,
               "lng" : -73.97736809999999
            }...
```

Comment: You're right ! It fixed my problems after I `urlencode($address)`. But may I asked I got 26 elements in my response array. How do I know which element is the one that will give me the accurate **lat,lng** ? Please advise.

Comment: It returns the location(s) that matches your given query which can be multiple addresses. 

If you just want the best suggestion for the given query use the lat/lng from the first result.